# Why the generated query use [Project1]?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

When I run the following linq query (asp.net MVC 5):

```
var source = from a in ControllerFactory.AuthRepository.Database.Announcements
             let d = date
             let start = a.start
             where (!useStartDateFilter || start <= d) &&  a.end > d
             orderby start
             select a;

var items = await source.Skip(CurrentPage * PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToListAsync();
```

The generated SQL query is:

```
SELECT 
[Project1].[id] AS [id], 
[Project1].[start] AS [start], 
[Project1].[end] AS [end], 
[Project1].[json_localized_annoucement] AS [json_localized_annoucement], 
[Project1].[json_localized_link] AS [json_localized_link]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
    [Extent1].[start] AS [start], 
    [Extent1].[end] AS [end], 
    [Extent1].[json_localized_annoucement] AS [json_localized_annoucement], 
    [Extent1].[json_localized_link] AS [json_localized_link]
    FROM [dbo].[Announcements] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ((@p__linq__0 <> 1) OR ([Extent1].[start] <= @p__linq__1)) AND ([Extent1].[end] > @p__linq__1)
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY row_number() OVER (ORDER BY [Project1].[start] ASC)
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

Can someone please explain why it generate the [Project1] part?

Is it avoidable? Maybe this projection has no effect on query performance?

Comment: Try removing `let` statements and using `a.start` and `date` in corresponding places. As for performance you should run this query against db profiler and compare it against one without subselect.

Comment: @GuruStron I already tried this and it seems to have no impact on the generated query, except it use p__linq__2 equal to p__linq__1

Comment: There is no any effect on query performance, it's just autogenerated [alias](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Comment: SQL is a language where you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Any other query that is *logically* the same as this one but expressed differently *should* end up with exactly the same plan after the optimizer is through with it.

Comment: Ok thanks I know SQL will optimize the query by itself but it should at least read the query. And this generated SQL query is longer than if I writted it myself. But I guess the performance cost is negligible...

Comment: Remember, premature optimization is the root of all evil. I can't conceive of a database where parsing the SQL query is going to take longer than retrieving the data - worry about the efficiency of translation after you have a performance problem. However, consider your second statement - it wraps the first query in `Skip().Take()` which is reflected exactly in the SQL. You could gain a little efficiency by pulling out the test of `useStartDateFilter` and optionally adding the `Where` to `source`.

Comment: @NetMage ok thanks I understand now why there is the second statement. So it's better to have multiple statements than the `useStartDateFilter ` inside the query? I don't know how SQL manage query with a bool that don't depend of the data.

Comment: LINQ to SQL/EF doesn't (AFAIK) evaluate local expressions, just translates them to SQL and sends them to the server. I would hope SQL optimizes with constant folding, but I am not positive. You would need to compare the execution plan for queries with the `useStartDateFilter` true and false. I think it is better to handle it on the LINQ side.